# GruntJS and custom task: require a RequireJS module

Tags: gruntjs, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am quite new with GruntJS and I wonder if it is possible to have a task that loads some RequireJs modules to process them and write the result within a JS file.

I describe my scenario:

I have a RequireJs based project with many files.
I would like to concatenate/minify/etc the project to deploy it and increase performances, etc.

The optimization works perfectly with the `grunt-contrib-requirejs` plugin.
The `grunt-contrib-requirejs` plugin works with a `main.js` file and I should need to generate it dynamically.

I would like to generate the `main.js` processing some RequireJS module of the project (call them `fileA.js` and `fileB.js`).
I would like to use the generated `main.js` to run the `grunt-contrib-requirejs` plugin.

So the task sequence would be something like:

Custom Task:

1. loads `fileA.js` and `fileB.js`
2. merge them together
3. write the result of the merging within a new JS file

`grunt-contrib-requirejs` task:

1. use the generated `main.js` file to optimize the project

Do you know how can I achieve this? 
I don't have any kind of restrictions on the way/tools/libs to use.

Comment: Do u want us to give you detailed code of the procedure you listed? procedure mentioned is standard way of doing, you just need to implement it...

Comment: @Vishwanath thank you for your reply. I will set a GitHub repository to show you what i mean. Thank you again.

Comment: @Vishwanath here you can find the project. https://github.com/danielefenix/requirejs-grunt-dynamic-main

Comment: What is the problem with staticMain.js?

Comment: Btw you can use phantom browser task to emulate the load and then read `requirejs.s.contexts._.defined` property from the top level object.

Comment: I can not rely on the staticMain.js because its RequireJS configuration is the object I would like to build dynamically during. My scenario is similar to the dynamic.html situation in which the RequireJS configuration comes from the merge of different files. This is a condition (that unfortunately i can not get rid of it from the project given its nature) that makes less effective the optimization with grunt-contrib-requirejs. That's why i would like to write the 'staticMain.js' with a grunt task from the files and give it as parameter of the next task (grunt-contrib-requirejs).

Comment: You told that it is possible to load the files with phantomjs. Would you mind to link an example of it? Would it be possible to write a file (e.g with grunt-writefile) from the phantomjs task (e.g the result of the merge)? @Vishwanath thank you very much for your kind support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load `RequireJS` in Grunt, as follows:

```js
var requirejs = require('requirejs');
```

You can then fetch all the `fileX.js` files in your tree through Grunt:

```js
grunt.file.recurse('js/modules/', function callback(abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename) {
    if (filename === 'fileX.js') {
      /* Do something here. */  
    }
}
```

Once you have all the modules you need you can use `r.js` to minify/concatenate them.